# Deploying Keras Models to Google Cloud Platform using latest Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning

I am following an Online Tutorial(2-3 years old) which teaches below steps for ML Model cloud deployment. But using Tensorflow 2.0, google team have updated many methods for building, saving and exporting our model written in python. Check my current code -

```
model_builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("exported_model")

inputs = {
    'input': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.input)
}
outputs = {
    'earnings': tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(model.output)
}

signature_def = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=outputs,
    method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
)

model_builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    K.get_session(),
    tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_def
    }
)

model_builder.save()
```

But now it is giving errors like - there are no such attributes

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.saved_model' has no attribute 'builder','utils'.
```

Also, Google cloud team has changed the name of their ML APIs on Google Cloud Platform now.
So, can anyone please suggest the exact steps including latest methods and APIs for deploying my ML model to GCP?

Comment: Do you want to deploy your model in batch mode? in online mode? into a serverless platform (AI Platform for example) or into a Cloud Function or on a VM?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am still in the learning phase, I just want to save, export and deploy to GCP through PyCharm using python so that I can use GCP command to predict with given input.

Comment: I would recommend starting by just using tensorflow < 2 if you want to follow that tutorial. Another alternative is use compatibility versions of the methods you are using. if you want to use tf 2 and you are just starting I would suggest looking for a tutorial where tf2 is used directly. If you want to learn about the whole training and deployment process I can recommend you "Machine Learning with Tensroflow on GCP" course in Coursera, there you have plenty of notebooks and provide you with temporary accounts on GCP so that you can try them yourself